# SQL Agent account vs. Proxy account

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2008

I have understood that if a job needs to access OS resources, it is recommended to create a SQL Server credential and proxy instead of using Agent account. Am I right? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good practice so that the SQL Agent jobs do not run under the SQL Agent service account, which normally has sysadmin rights on the SQL instance and local administrator rights on the SQL Server host.  Also, if you need to access UNC shares or web services from the Agent job then they can be done under the context of the proxy/credential account instead of the SQL agent account.